# How to change img src in view MVC

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, image, view

This is my image:

```
<img id="1star" src="~/Content/Images/emptystar.png" onmouseover="setStars(1)" onmouseout="setStarsBack()" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("SetRating", "CreativeModels", new { id = GlobalVariables.CurrentBookId, rating = 1 })'" />
```

this is the code of function that should change the image source:

```
function setStars(amount) {
   if (amount > 0) {
     document.getElementById("1star").src = "~/Content/Images/filledstar.png";
   }
}
```

It changes but browser says, that it can't load the image. This is what browser shows after moving mouse to the pictures:

[image: image of what browser shows]

And this is picture of how images looked before moving mouse to them:

[image: image with starts rendered]

How should I change `src` property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not with the src attribute. That is changed correctly to what you've set it to. The problem is that it's pointing to the wrong directory.

Assuming that you're using razor with your MVC solution try this out:

```
function setStars(amount) {
   if (amount > 0) {
     document.getElementById("1star").src = "@Url.Content("~/Content/Images/filledstar.png")";
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to base your image `URL` on the current html file position. Actually, using `~` in your image `URL`, you are assuming that it is located under the current user home folder. But if the user change, than `~` will point to the new user home folder.

I suggest to you to change the current the value of the `src` tag to this:

```
<pathOfHtmlFile>/Content/Images/filledstar.png
```

and replace `<pathOfHtmlFile>` with the path where the html file is located on your computer.

Comment: I changed it to `"E:/Kursovoi/Super Backup/Eksperement c vistavleniem otsenok/WebApplication4/WebApplication4/Views/CreativeModels/Content/Images/emptystar.png"`, but it changes nothing. I guess browser can only acess pictures on server, which i don't have. And I don't have html file, I have cshtml file.

Comment: @VladimirMootin This is not a server problem, I tried to reproduced the issue on my pc, but I got the expected result. Could you add to your question the output of your browser console? This can help to solve the issue.